# Is Yuuki bi/homosexual?

Tags: sword-art-online

In Sword Art Offline 2 7 when Yuuki learned that Asuna was married in-game and she and Kirito had Yui as their daughter, she started saying how she would want to marry Asuna and make her happy and have many babies with her (not knowing how babies are made). This also seems to spark a rivalry between her and Kirito in Sword Art Offline 2 7.

I remember reading that Yuuki in real life is also female and there is some fanart of an Asuna x Yuuki pairing [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SavwD.jpg), [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBzvc.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geErE.jpg).

Now I know that like any other pairing, fanbase shoujo ai/yuri fans would jump at Yuuki's comments in Sword Art Offline. However i am wondering if there is any evidence that indicates that Yuuki is bi/homosexual and that her comments in Sword Art Offline are sincere, that she would want to marry Asuna and (with her limited understanding of hwo) have babies with her.

EDIT: by bi/homosexual I am referring to if Yuuki would have deeper feeling for the same sex.

Comment: Please define bisexual and homosexual. There are many meanings that can be applied, and the answers can vary by the meaning you accept by "bi/homosexual".

Comment: @ardaozkal please check the edit, however I wouldn't think I need to explain it more since I point out Yuuki's comments in Sword Art Offline and the fan art

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As someone who's only ever watched the anime series, and someone who's actually consulted some outside help to better explain this, I can reasonably answer:

## No.

It isn't uncommon for two girls or two women to hold some kind of affection or level of respect for one another in some capacity.  From my sources, to suggest that they would consider "making babies" with each other implies an opinion that this woman is indeed attractive.

However - and this is a point my source ***thoroughly*** stressed - this does not, in *any* way, imply any form of sexual orientation.

Further to this, given the interactions that Yuuki had with Asuna throughout Mother's Rosario, my impression is that Yuuki held admiration, respect, and love - the kind of love that you'd get from a close family member.  The rivalry between her and Kirito can be seen as more friendly than her trying to one-up Kirito in an effort to win Asuna over.

I also sense a level of admiration and respect from Yuuki of Asuna, given that

> Yuuki is terminally ill and can't really explore the world, which prompted Kazuto to develop technical equipment to allow her to see the world in which she previously existed in, with Asuna's help.  This helped her gain more closure with her situation and, in my assessment, feels more like something an older sister would take on.

With that, I can safely and reasonably conclude that there's no implication whatsoever of Yuuki's sexual orientation.  Respect or admiration of someone who seems awesome from their perspective seems more plausible.

<sup>Oh, and don't read too deeply into what fanart depicts.  Give 'em an inch and they'll run to Jupiter with one or two fleeting glances.</sup>